# How to rebase a branch onto another branch than the upstream branch?

Tags: git, rebase

While developing a `feat` branch based on the `develop` branch, the `develop` branch has been frozen, that is merged into the `staging` branch. So now I would like to rebase my `feat` branch onto `staging`.

Initial version history:

```
  D---E feat
 /
A---B---C develop
     \
  F---G---H staging
```

Final version history (what I want to get):

```
A---B---C develop
     \
  F---G---H staging
           \
            D---E feat
```

Final version history (what I will get with the `git rebase develop feat` command):

```
          D---E feat
         /
A---B---C develop
     \
  F---G---H staging
```

Which `git` command will set the initial version history into the desired state?

Comment: Should `git rebase develop feat` be `git rebase staging feat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would say

```
git rebase --onto staging develop feat
```

in order to get "what I want to get".

(This kind of move comes with a risk of merge conflicts but there's nothing you can do about that; any way of performing this move would entail the same risk.)

Comment: In this specific case, if the ASCII chart is accurate, it could be pulled off with `git rebase staging feat` **but** the way you provide there, @matt works as well _and_ is more easily understandable for anyone trying to move stuff around. I am upvoting it

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes `git rebase staging feat` works too because the common ancestor of `feat` and `staging` is the same as the common ancestor of `feat` and `develop` so the same commits `D` and `E` are rebased. If we ignore commits `C` and `F` in the graph it’s very clear. I accepted matt’s solution because it’s more general, it doesn’t require `develop` to be merged into `staging` to work.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you're on the feature branch: `git checkout feat`

If you need to, use `git pull` to update your branches.

Then use this command to rebase to the staging branch: `git rebase staging`

I hope this helps!

Comment: This works too because the common ancestor of `feat` and `staging` is the same as the common ancestor of `feat` and `develop` so the same commits `D` and `E` are rebased. If we ignore commits `C` and `F` in the graph it’s very clear. Thanks.